# Does it make sense to use Paging SQL Statement when using Slick (JDBC) Connector for Alpakka

Tags: scala, slick, akka-stream, alpakka

I'm currently wondering how Slick (JDBC) Connector for Alpakka works under the hood - And I can't really find an answer using the Docs.

Considering a use case where I want to process a large number of records selected from a database. Can I simply use a `SELECT * FROM [TABLE]` in a single stream, or does it make sense to start multiple streams for each page (one after the other) like `SELECT * FROM [TABLE] LIMIT 0,1000`.

I hope/ think that the reactive fashion of the Slick Connector Alpakka takes care of only fetching records from the database when the stream needs them so that I can use the `SELECT * FROM [TABLE]` ...

Can anyone give me some insights or some good docs to read through?

Comment: I just also found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565612/streaming-in-slick-scala?rq=1) - his tests seem to indicate that my assumption (we don't need to make paged requests) is true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the source code for Alpakka's [`Slick.source`](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/v0.16/slick/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/slick/scaladsl/Slick.scala#L38) method:

```
/**
 * Scala API: creates a Source[T, NotUsed] that performs the
 *            specified query against the (implicitly) specified
 *            Slick database and streams the results.
 *            This works for both "typed" Slick queries
 *            and "plain SQL" queries.
 *
 * @param streamingQuery The Slick query to execute, which can
 *                       be either a "typed" query or a "plain SQL"
 *                       query produced by one of the Slick "sql..."
 *                       String interpolators
 * @param session The database session to use.
 */
def source[T](
    streamingQuery: StreamingDBIO[Seq[T], T]
)(implicit session: SlickSession): Source[T, NotUsed] =
  Source.fromPublisher(session.db.stream(streamingQuery))
```

`session.db.stream(streamingQuery))` above results in a [`DatabasePublisher`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/api/index.html#slick.basic.DatabasePublisher), which is a Reactive Streams `Publisher` that is passed to Akka Stream's `Source.fromPublisher`. Don't be concerned about trying to create multiple streams for subsets of the data; you can safely use a query that retrieves all the rows in a table and work with the resulting `Source` as a single stream.

One thing to note is that you may need to configure a few settings as mentioned not in the Alpakka documentation, but in the [Slick documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/dbio.html#streaming):

> Note: Some database systems may require session parameters to be set in a certain way to support streaming without caching all data at once in memory on the client side. For example, PostgreSQL requires both `.withStatementParameters(rsType = ResultSetType.ForwardOnly, rsConcurrency = ResultSetConcurrency.ReadOnly, fetchSize = n)` (with the desired page size `n`) and `.transactionally` for proper streaming.

So if you're using PostgreSQL, for example, then your `Source` might look something like the following:

```
val source =
  Slick.source(
    TableQuery[Items]
      .result
      .withStatementParameters(
        rsType = ResultSetType.ForwardOnly,
        rsConcurrency = ResultSetConcurrency.ReadOnly,
        fetchSize = 10
      )
      .transactionally)
```

[`TableQuery[Items].result`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/schemas.html#table-query) returns all the rows in the table associated with `Items`.

The documentation notwithstanding, I've successfully used Slick's `DatabasePublisher` in conjunction with Akka Streams to retrieve and update millions of rows from a table in PostgreSQL without setting `withStatementParameters` or `transactionally`. Try it without those settings:

```
val source = Slick.source(TableQuery[Items].result)
```